# "Have got" in BrE

Tags: british-english, transatlantic-differences, have-got

I'm confused, is "have got" a verb? Because when I've searched it in a dictionary, it said "have got" was an equivalent of "have", the form is like  the "Present Perfect Tense", and it is the equivalent of "have" in British English. I've ever heard that "have got" can't be used in every situation, and only "have" can be used in all situation and all verbs, is that right?

These are the examples. So, do you hear them in standard British English?

1. I have already got to go (or) I already have to go.
2. I never have a pen when I need one (or) I have never got a pen when I need one.
3. I have got to do it (or) I have to do it.
4. I have still got to sign those contracts (or) I still have to sign those contracts.
5. I have just/only got five pence (or) I just/only have five pence.

---

**Questions**
Do you use them both in BrE? What are the differences between them? Could you tell me, is "have got" a verb?

Comment: We **have** a lot of newcomers who ask this type of question, so don't be dismayed if nobody rushes to answer. Did you write these examples yourself, or did you find them online somewhere? A few seem to miss the mark, they're not very idiomatic sounding.

Comment: @Mari-LouA , Yes! I found them online and I made these sentences myself. But, are they correct?

Comment: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/usage-of-never.3309688/ why did the answers on this website not satisfy you? There's nothing wrong in asking in more than website, but you should include the research, and explain what you don't understand.

Comment: As I mentioned previously, the samples do not sound very idiomatic ["I already have to go"](https://www.google.it/search?q=I+already+have+to+go&oq=I+already+have+to+go&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64l3&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=%22I+already+have+to+go%22&tbm=bks) produces only three results on Google books.

Comment: You're confusing "have got" = possession, e.g. *He* ***has got a*** *new car* and   *have got to* = must, e.g. *He* **has got to get** *a new car, his old one is falling to bits*

Comment: @Mari-LouA, So, I've recently heard, that "have got" is an informal form and "have" is a formal form, so do you use "do" support in e.g. I do have/I have, I don't have, do/don't I have?, I've seen "have" without "do" and "got" is it more common in BrE?

Comment: You're confusing the meanings, it's HAVE GOT + noun (*We have got two cars* BrEng) and HAVE GOT TO + verb sometimes shortened to GOT TO + verb ( *We have got to get  some new cars* = we must/have to get some new cars) The question form would be: *Do we HAVE TO GET new cars?* or *HAVE we GOT TO get new cars*?"

Comment: please read this answer, if it doesn't help, explain *why* in your question. Link the older question in your question so users don't have to search where you got the information from. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4193/could-i-always-use-have-and-never-use-have-got/4229#4229

Comment: SIX questions about "have got" are far too many. Please visit ELL, English language for Learners, it is a sister site that caters *especially* for learners  who are at beginner or pre intermediate level https://ell.stackexchange.com/ just click where it says **join this community** in the top bar. No need to change your account or anything.